# Transactional Replication from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I wanted to ask about Your experience related to set up a Transactional replication between SQL SERVER 2008R2 (publisher) and SQL SERVER 2017 (subscriber).

I know that this is not supported by Microsoft according to "Transactional & Snapshot Replication compatibility matrix", [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15).

But I set up this kind of transactional replication (2008R2 -> 2017) on a few databases and it works without any errors. So the question is when or in what kind of situation (maybe some special type of configuration, user-defined data types...), this replication could stop to work or generate errors?

Answer (score 0):

Support for SQL Server 2008 R2 has ended, so everything you do is unsupported.

In this configuration (2008 Publisher/Distributor/Push Subscription) all replication activity is driven from the SQL 2008 R2 instance, and with a SQL 2014 subscriber this *was* a supported configuration.

So the only thing that would break is if SQL 2017 somehow behaved differently than SQL 2014 did.  To minimize the likelihood of issues keep the subscriber in 100 or 120 database compatibility level.  130 compatibility level introduced some [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-design/sql-server-azure-sql-database-improvements).